# Highlighting wrong columns

Tags: testing, automation, fitnesse, dbfit, fit-framework

I'm using Fitnesse + dbFit to verify data in one database table.
If at least one column in a record is wrong the whole record is highlighted. Do you know if Fitnesse can highlight only wrong columns ?

My table has over 100 columns and even if I get information which row is wrong I have to spend much time trying to find a column that contains wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

The fitSharp version of DbFit highlights the cell in error.  See http://fitsharp.github.com/

Comment: thanks for reply, you can also add "?" to the column name in Fit then it also shows an error in the cell.